# Not able to add markers on the OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers

I have a following short HTML code, which displays a map. I can't find any way to add a marker on this map. I've tried different examples, but everything's failed so far. Here I post one of the codes I've tried.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/css/ol.css">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="mymap" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    <script>      

    var icon = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([16.9278, 52.4044], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
    });

    var iconLayerSource = new ol.layer.Vector({
        features: [icon]
    });

    var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: iconLayerSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                src:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Map_marker_font_awesome.svg/200px-Map_marker_font_awesome.svg.png'
            })
        })
    })

    var map = new ol.Map({
        view: new ol.View({center: ol.proj.transform([16.9278, 52.4044], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), zoom:12}),
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        iconLayer],
        target:'mymap'
    });



    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in your browser's console? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/get-started

Comment: See this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835153/add-marker-to-map-using-openlayers-and-angular-6). This related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316902/7635569) indicates the `OpenLayers.Marker` has been deprecated in OL2, while you are using OL5.

Comment: I've updated the code. It's still not working. I can't see the map nor the icon, just the "zoom" tool on the left side of the screen. When I remove the "iconLayer" reference from the "layers" in "map" variable, I can see the map, but not the icon.

Comment: Correct `var iconLayerSource = new ol.layer.Vector({` to `var iconLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector({` and it should work.